# Why are built-in functions in Python from a different type than user defined functions?

Tags: python

I noticed that the type of `abs` is `builtin_function_or_method`, which is different from a user defined function which is of type `function`. Instances of `builtin_function_or_method` don't have the func_name attribute, while instances of `function` do. Why is there a separation between the types?

Comment: Because they're implemented in C, not Python. See e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.BuiltinFunctionType - *"Here, the term “built-in” means “written in C”."*

Comment: This belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com